# Git commit failed : Couldn't load public key

Tags: git, gnupg, gpg-signature

I cannot commit to  git . Every time I try it shows this message.

```
error: Couldn't load public key 632EA751459C3A1A: No such file or directory?

fatal: failed to write commit object
```

I'm using Gpg4Win.

Comment: Running into this issue as well, with a recently new update of Gpg4Win.  It was working before.  :shrug:  If you've resolved this I'd love to know what it took.  Assuming that gnupg can't find the pubring it created.

Answer (score 28):

I believe I resolved my issue, perhaps it is the same for you.  For some reason I'd set the `gpg.format` value to "SSH" in my local Git config.

Simply removing that from my ~/.gitconfig allowed Gpg4Win to resolve the correct location of the key.

Comment: The correct and safer way is to `git config --global --unset gpg.format`

Comment: same thing happened to me (on Mac ). no idea how it got there..

Answer (score 3):

[Telling Git about your signing key](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/telling-git-about-your-signing-key)

To sign commits locally, you need to inform Git that there's a GPG, SSH, or X.509 key you'd like to use.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your ssh agent turned on and running. I have closed strongbox (my password manager and ssh agent) and it has shown this error. The fix is to simply turn your ssh agent on...

Answer (score -3):

remove `format = ssh`  from `~/.gitconfig`

Comment: What does this add to Kit Plummer's answer?

Comment: quick and dirty. Simpler.